# How to read all excel data with Matlab COM server

Tags: excel, matlab, com-server

I need to read very large excel data and I want to calculate it. My data have so much sheets and every sheet has much columns and number of columns isn't specific (e.g: Sheet1 have 150 columns but Sheet2 have 3000 columns) however number of rows are known.

```
get(Excel.Activesheet.UsedRange)
```

This code is not working because it select only 256 columns. So, I need to know number of columns for different sheets. Can you help me?

Comment: The `.xls` file contain only data, or equations?

Comment: data integer and string

Comment: Have you tried `xlsfinfo` and `xlsread` functions?

Comment: yep but data are very huge so xlsread is very slower than activex.

Comment: Is the data represented in the same format in all your files? E.g. a string header row, a string column and double columns? If so, If you can upload an example file or just post a simple example here, I am sure I can get what you need.

Comment: I can't share, website isnt permit to me

Comment: I have 20 .xls files each file have 150 sheets and each sheet have 803 rows and x columns, some cells contain strin e.g Hz dB and some cells double e.g 98.87

Comment: for j=1:2 Location = [xlcolumn(j) '1:' xlcolumn(j) '803'];
           ResultValue  = get(Excel.Activesheet, 'Range',Location);
           ResultValue.Select;
            
        end

Comment: Can you provide typical example of the structure of the sheets?

Comment: Freq 0.2 sec 0.4 sec 0.6 sec 0.8 sec 1 sec
Hz db db db db db
0 93,39 95,4 98,32 95,01 99,94
25 77,37 77,95 80,97 78,72 80,73

Comment: Please add it to the question, it is easier to format it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209193/how-to-read-all-excel-data-with-com-server-update