# How to read all excel data with com server update

Tags: excel, matlab, com-server

```
for j=1:???
Loc = [func(j) '1:' func(j) '803'];

Result = get(Excel.Activesheet, 'Range', Loc);

Result.Select;

expResult = Excel.Selection.Value
```

`func` converts number to character of excel column. I want to read all data. If I write a number for `???` e.g 100 only Read 100 columns.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to read an xls file or do you actually have to get the active sheet from Excel?

Comment: if I give a value for j, I can read sheets or files but I want to read all columns and only filled columns. Some sheets have 30 some sheets have 150 columns

Comment: Have you tried the `xlsread` function? It's documentation can be found here: http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html